# Customize Highlight color of items in NavDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am looking for a way to customize the Highlight color of items in navigation drawer like in picture above in "Inbox" item.

i want to change heights and edges of highlight press color ..

How can i do that ?

many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**inside drawer_item.xml do something like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="checked state color" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="your default color" />
</selector>
```

**change your NavigationView**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigationview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"  // notice here
app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item" // and here
app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"// and here for setting the background 
color to tranparent
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
```

Comment: where can i find "drawer_item.xml" .. I dont have one @Yomesh Mistri

Comment: You can put color app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"  //  here
app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item" and here also

Comment: ok.But How can i change the "heights" of items background color .. I want to  customize it ..@Yomesh Mistri